# Twitter Button Only Show Tweet Text, No Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

After several hours of going through posts here and google, I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here.

I am attempting to put a twitter tweet button on a website. I've backed the code down to pretty much out of the box, yet no button loads, and the link goes to a webpage, not the popup module. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world"
data-size="large">
Tweet</a>

<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
t = window.twttr || {};
if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
js = d.createElement(s);
js.id = id;
js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

t._e = [];
t.ready = function(f) {
t._e.push(f);
};

return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

I feel like I'm not properly including a JS file or a CSS file, but I do not know as to what that would be.

I have also attempted adding twitter-wjs as an id element on the link, and including the

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

as that seemed to have helped others, but no luck there either. My console log is running clean, and I can see the JS showing up in the source after the a link, so that should all be fine.

The site is in PHP, Phalcon Framework. JQuery is enabled. NGINX. SSL is also enabled. Bootstrap is also being leveraged.

Thank you again for any help, this is driving me insane.